# Wordpress and IIS. Deploy two servers at one domain

Tags: php, iis, domain, .net

I want to add a wordpress blod on my site running on IIS. How can I do so?

e.g My blog URL will be www.mydomain.com/blog

I tried to install PHP server(wamp), but it did not run due to port conflict. After changing port my url becomes e.g:

**www.mydomain.com**

**www.mydomain.com:1005/blog**

I want to run both my site and blog on same domain without any port in the URL. How can I overcome this port conflict.

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: How can I run 2 servers on One port?

Comment: Maybe if you expanded your question to include what version of *anything* you're running, as well as what you've done so far, you may get someone to help you, instead of immediate closure.

Comment: So where does IIS come into this? Is that already installed? I can only assume WAMP wouldn't use port 80 because IIS was already using it. In that case, there are plenty of guides around showing you how to load the PHP module into IIS.

Comment: yes IIS already installed.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Web Platform installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) - find WordPress and it will install all necessary prerequisites including php ISAPI extension for IIS and MySQL. Installation wizard will guide you. You must have host header assigned to your Web site and install WordPress to blog web application on your web site.

Btw. questions about configuring IIS belong to [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/) and questions about configuring wordpress belong to [wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Installing WAMP is not necessary since you already have IIS installed. IIS is already listening on port 80, so the sensible thing to do would be to load the PHP DLL into IIS and run your blog on IIS.

As for loading PHP into IIS, the download contains a file called `install.txt` which goes through how to install PHP (failing that, there's no end of guides on the internet). If you're not particularly comfortable with that, the [PHP download page](http://windows.php.net/download/) offers an MSI installer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Upload wordpress files to a directory called /blog/ in your web root.

Comment: will wordpress run without php server? How can I install 2 servers at 1 port?